# Words for meat differ from the words for the corresponding animal

Tags: vocabulary, list-request

In English we have:

- "beef" for "cow", "cattle"
- "veal" for "calf"
- "pork" for "pig"
- "mutton" for "sheep"

I'm not aware of this separation for "fish", "goat" or "chicken" (Spanish has "pollo" and "gallina") and other poultry. Are these words used simply to distinguish the meat from the animal (i.e. to avoid saying "cow meat") or is there a psychological separation to avoid the association? I doubt the latter since these words developed when people were likely less squeamish than some are today.

Why are there not meat words for some animals?

What are some others I didn't list?

Comment: Although I can’t think of any other such example, Spanish has *pez* for a fish in the sea and *pescado* for one on your plate.  And yes, that’s originally a past participle of *pescar*, to fish.  So the fish you eat has been fished. Different reason altogether compared with what happened in English, but it’s the only non-English example that springs quickly to mind.

Comment: Oh, and you forgot that English uses calamari/calamares for squid you eat and escargot for snails you eat. Weird.

Comment: @tchrist Technically calamari and squid are different things, both in the sea and on your plate. Some fishmongers will try and rip you off, though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe that many of these come from the use of French in England amongst the aristocracy after the Norman conquest. Thus 'pork' (porc) is the posh word, 'pig' is the vulgar peasant (or English) word. I don't have any reference for this, but I heard it somewhere in my travels. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it does sound like a convincing story.

Comment: It sounds convincing, but it happens in other languages too.  While it's alive, the French "boeuf" is a "vache."  Pig is "chochon" until it's killed and becomes "porc." That said, a calf is "veau" whether it's been butchered or not and a sheep is "mouton" even when it's mutton.

Comment: I was thinking of it in terms of "culinary" words being rooted in the French and "agricultural" words rooted in the Germanic, but Boofus's point is well taken.

Comment: The usual story is that during the norman conquest, the poor farmers were too poor to eat meat, and the French rulers never saw the animals, which is why the words for the meat have French etymologies, and the words for the animals are Anglo-Saxon. _Something_ like that might be true, but the true details probably aren't as tidy.

Comment: I believe Sir Walter Scott referenced this story in *Ivanhoe*, so it has been around since at least the early 19th century; but given Ivanhoe's overall level of historical accuracy, I wouldn't put much stock in it as a source.

Comment: Melvyn Bragg talked about this in his excellent "Adventure of English" TV series (and presumably also in the book). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventure_of_English

Comment: At least in some contexts, French uses "boeuf" for the animal: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_b%C5%93uf_sur_le_toit

Comment: In French you can call a pig either "cochon" or "porc".  The French-language show I watched as a child (Passe-Partout) has a song where they sing about pigs living in "la porcherie".  One of the characters asks why they don't live in "une cochonnerie".

Comment: @Colin: Occasionally you'll hear Americans use "beeves" for "cattle".

Comment: @Boofus, it's a bit more complicated than that: `boeuf` (the meat) can come from a `vache` (heffer), `taureau` (bull) or `boeuf` (steer/bullock = castrated bull). [(from Yahoo answers, in French)](http://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061002081707AAWNcgg)

Comment: @Benjol, I had thought my French was just barely enough to give a counter example -- apparently, it's even weaker than I'd thought.

Comment: @Boofus, well I had to go and look it up to make sure, as my first reaction was that `boeuf` was male and `vache` was female. You live and learn...

Comment: @RichardA, I would modify your answer (even though it is already accepted) to state that the *edible* words clearly *do* derive from French, and the *live* ones from ('old') English. I don't think there can be any doubt about that. What is in doubt is the posh/vulgar myth, which *is* disputed (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymology, under English language)

Answer (score 10):

> What are some others I didn't list?

- [Venison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venison) for deer
- [Squab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squab_%28food%29) for pigeon
- [Chevon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goat_meat) for goat
- [Carabeef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carabeef) for buffalo
- [Long pig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannibalism) for human

Comment: carabeef is for water buffalo

Comment: Soylent Green is people!

Answer (score 5):

A cow is made up of more than its meat so referring to the muscle with a different name to the entire animal isn't that hard to swallow. How the meat is prepared and even the age of the animal can give the meat a different name too. e.g. pork, bacon and ham or lamb and mutton.

Why some animals have this distinction and not others is something I'm unsure of. This is a bit of history surrounding the beef/cow words on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beef#Etymology

Answer (score 2):

Human meat has been called "long pig", so you could add

- "long pig" for "human"

As for words for meat, how about "sweetbreads" or "tripe" for offal? These seem like euphemisms to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think this Wikipedia article pretty well answers the question:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English_creole_hypothesis

Answer (score -1):

For psychological reasons, the names of most meats are different from the animals they come from. The meat industry has always tried to disassociate the meat from the animal. For example, most meat eaters are fine with eating "beef," but if it were labeled "cow," they might think twice about eating it. Same with sheep, goats, pigs, and deer.

Comment: The names predate the modern squeamishness by centuries, at least.

Comment: And yet people are much happier to eat lamb than mutton; hence 'mutton dressed as lamb".

Comment: Mutton has a much stronger, gamier flavor than lamb.  A preference for one or the other is based on an actual difference.  I had heard "mutton dressed as lamb" as a humorous metaphor for a woman dressing as a girl.

Answer (score -3):

- *beef* for cattle
- *carabeef* for buffalo
- *mutton* for sheep
- *chevon* for goat
- *vension* for deer
- *veal* for calf
- *game* for rabbit

Comment: No, rabbit is *coney*, not *game*.

Comment: *game* may include rabbit, but also partridge, pheasant and other wildfowl, as well as venison; essentially, anything shot rather than slaughtered.

Comment: This answer can be improved by citing sources for the information.